# How To Prevent Uploading From Interrupting When Screen Is Off?

Tags: screen, internet, data-connection, youtube, battery-life

When screen goes off, uploads get interrupted especially YouTube uploads and everytime i have to resume phone to continue uploads. The problem is that in case of YouTube, videos stutter which i assume at the moment upload was interrupted.

I have **[JuiceDefender Plus](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender.plus&hl=en)** just to add. Is there a way to prevent uploads from interrupting, at least by instructing the screen not to turn off when uploading?

**UPDATE:** What i want is to be able to keep screen turned on while uploading.

*HTC Desire S*
*Android 2.3.3 (unrooted)*

Answer (score 4):

*Settings -> Wireless & Network -> Wi-fi settings.*
Press the [Menu/Options] button, and select *Advanced*

Now choose in the Wi-fi sleep policy : *Never*

Keep in mind that your battery is going to drain faster (because the wifi will never be turned off unless you manually do it), and is easy to forget that you changed the sleep policy.

Answer (score 2):

You may try checking the *Settings* -> *Applications* -> *Development* -> *Stay awake* checkbox. Note a caveat mentioned in the Android manual: "Don’t use this setting with a static image on the phone for long periods of time, or the screen may be marked with that image."

Comment: It is only when charging. Don't get the last part about "screen marking".

Comment: _screen marking_ refers to a problem that happends when you leave a screen turned on with a static image for too long. The screen gets _marked_ with that image (more like burned), and will look permanently like a watermark in a sheet of paper. It depends on the technology of your screen, but you should not worry about it.